# Delete cached video from Photo gallery iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I am caching a recorded video to convert it into NSData and upload on a server.
I have got the URL/File Path of that video.
How can I delete the cached video?
I have tried following code

```
do {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    //Delete Cached Video
    // Check if file exists
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: self.videoDeletionURL!.absoluteString) {
        // Delete file
        try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: self.videoDeletionURL!.absoluteString)
    } else {
        print("File does not exist")
    }
```

This code is not workig. It prints "File does not exist"
A working code will be apreciated. Regards

Comment: Its obtained from video recording session output URL. Using SCRecorder for recording the video.
Its something like "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AD8DFF74-354A-497A-976D-B0073C2F876A/tmp/6yWofdiwph7x-SCVideo-Merged.mov"

Comment: Yes, it prints "File does not exist".
file is in gallery on manual check

Comment: Above error is gone, but file is still in the gallery :)

Comment: It didn't show any error either. no error caught